Solana Program Deploy command failing due to llc text sections Error
The deploy command is failing. How can I fix this error. I found no documentation about this error. After running cargo-build-sbf in my hello_world test project I get this error:
$ solana program deploy -C ./solana-config.yml ./target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/solana_program-36c591929de80c52.so
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections

I am running this under macOS.
$ cargo-build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.9
platform-tools v1.41
rustc 1.75.0


You're trying to deploy a shared object version of one of the libraries that is eventually linked into your final Solana program, which won't work because it's not the actual program!
The name is a bit confusing, but solana-program actually refers to the library used for developing programs on Solana: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/sdk/program
Instead, be sure to deploy the fully built program, which should be found in ./target/deploy/ and have your program's name in it, ie hello_world.so
